# TortoiseSVN: "The patch seems outdated"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, patch

I'm creating a patch on trunk and, when applying it to another branch, get "The patch seems outdated" error. I didn't find a resolution on Google. The trunk has just been merged to the branch.

I'm using 64bit TortoiseSVN v1.63 on Windows 7.

Comment: In your branch, have changes been made to the files that you are trying to patch that were not merged into trunk? Could you do a diff of the files you are patching on the branch?

Comment: Yes, changes were probably made on the branch that were not merged to trunk. I worked around the problem by simply copying the diff manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing an svn up before you try to checkin the new patch?